# Matching condition in python with JSON

Tags: python

I have the following JSON file:

```
[
    {
     "key":1,
     "subject": "Phone1 not found",
     "description": "The client's site is utilizing a 3rd party's DNI javascript.  In order for us to track all calls, please ask the client to provide all possible DNI numbers.  We have found the following numbers: "
    },
    {
        "key":2,
        "subject": "Phone1 not matching",
        "description": "Phone1 is not matching. How it's going on"
    },
    {
    "key":3,
    "subject": "Query Parameters",
    "description": "We have tried to set this campaign on tracking, but on capture site we are facing tracking issues. We noticed query string parameters are not getting accepted on clients original site.<br> Example :    Query string should look like -https://www.nhtampabay.com?scid=xxxxxxx&cid=xxxxxxx. <br> Please ask the advertiser to pass the below query parameter through their server, <br>?scid=xxxxxxx&cid=xxxxxxx&tc=xxxxxxxxxx&rl_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&dynamic_proxy=1&primary_serv=www.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com&rl_track_landing_pages=1&rl_retarget=1 <br>This is original site issue and is not accepting our query string parameters for Reachcode functionality in the same way we have passed.   Please ask advertiser to contact their web master to update the original site in such a way that it accepts our query string parameters in the same way it is expected.   Reachcode site will work fine once the above said changes will be made on original site. The advertiser needs to allow our full query to pass through and not redirect."
    }
]
```

I am taking input from the user and segregating the input if ("&" or"and") are found in the list declared as splitresult. if the list(splitresult) contains some of the matching parameters(not found) of the subject(Phone1 not found) of JSON then the corresponding description will appended into matching_descriptions.

```
def ticketTemplate(myText):
    splitresult = re.split(r'\s*&\s*|\s*and\s*', myText)
    print(splitresult)
    matching_descriptions = []

    with open('ticket_template.json', 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()

    obj = json.loads(data)

    for data1 in obj:
               
                if any(keyword in splitresult in data1["subject"] for keyword in ['not found', 'not present']):
                   
                    matching_descriptions.append(data1["description"])

    if matching_descriptions:
        return '\n'.join(matching_descriptions)
    else:
        return "No Such Template Available. Please try again"
```

Any Help will be appreciated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the JQ bindings for Python, which let you query JSON-like data structures JQ filters.

Comment: *"Let me know if you have any questions"* - Let *us* know if *you* have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get the `description` content from json object if `subject` contains a text input part.

```py
import json
import re

def get_json_data():
    with open('ticket_template.json', 'r') as f:
        return json.load(f)

def ticket_template(data: list, query: str):
    
    # "not found & not matching"
    # produces ["not found", "not matching"]
    queries = re.split(r'\s*&\s*|\s*and\s*', query)

    def filter_match(obj: dict):
        # check each query inside of queries
        return any([q in obj.get("subject", "") for q in queries])

    # use filter function to get all match objects
    matches = list(filter(filter_match, data))
    if not matches:
        return "No Such Template Available. Please try again"

    # return description of each match object
    return '\n'.join([m["description"] for m in matches])
```

To prevent read the json file every time the function is called, receive the list by parameter (`data`). In case it is really necessary, you can remove the data parameter and call `get_json_data` inside `ticket_template`.

E.g.

```py
data = get_json_data()
ticket_template(data, "not found & not matching")


# Output: "The client's site is utilizing a 3rd party's DNI javascript.  In order for us to track all calls, please ask the client to provide all possible DNI numbers.  We have found the following numbers: \nPhone1 is not matching. How it's going on"
```

Comment: Thanks, Lucas! the issue is now that if I am passing the following parameters:

ticket_template(data, "Phone one not found & Phone one not matching"), it should return the same values.

Comment: because the input contains "not found" and "not matching, " these match with the subject of JSON file.